# Netbeans plugin for Apache Geronimo 3

Tags: java, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins, geronimo

Does there exist a Netbeans plugin for Geronimo 3?

I can't get to work the one for Geronimo 2 with a Geronimo 3 installation (which makes sense) and cannot find one for Geronimo 3.